# Which one is better? To have link on one page or on all pages?

Tags: seo, links

I have a website: http://www.amenajari-gradini-mures.ro and I will put links on http://www.casesigradini.ro .
I would like to know which one is better from the point of view of SEO: 
- to have one single link on the homepage OR
- to have a link on every page (about 48000 pages) ?

Right now I got my link up on every page. But if it's better to have it on one page only (or maybe on few main pages ) then i'll take it out the rest.

Please give some arguments for your answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Linking from many pages on one site to another isn't considered spam - plenty of sites have affiliations with other sites (case in point: the Stack Exchange network links at the bottom of this page). Furthermore, a link from one site to another can only increase PageRank, not decrease it.

Linking from thousands of pages is likely to decrease the *value* of each link, however, I'm sure 48,000 low-value links is as good or better than one link from the home page. It's pretty difficult to know exactly how Google treats these sorts of links.

Answer (score 1):

One link is better. If you place too many links then Google might see it as spam and reduce the ranking of your site. You need to focus on quality links from good reputation sites, not the quantity.

Comment: even if the topic of all the sites are relevant to my site's topic?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't do things that Google considers to be spam. Links are supposed to be generated over time so if a lot of them appear all-at-once Google might get suspicious and maybe even ban your site.

Comment: I disagree. DisgruntledGoat's answer is more accurate.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that @DisgruntledGoat and yourself are more informed on the subject than I so I guess he's correct. Thanks for the correction. I tried to answer a few SEO questions on this site but gave up as I found it to be too subjective for me to be able to give quality answers. I'm more familiar with programming topics where solutions either work or not and generally find with SEO that the answer always seems to come down to the statement 'Only Google knows'.